# What does this MOSFET circuit do?

Tags: mosfet, analog-switch

I have an N-channel MOSFET (Q6) whose drain is attached to the gate of a P-channel MOSFET (Q3). BAT+ (at the source of Q3) is +12 V. What is it doing?

Is there a way to accomplish this same function with only one FET?

[image]

Comment: What do you think it does? And if it could be achieved with one MOSFET, don't you think  they would have done so?

Comment: what has you believe the designers of this circuit were professional engineers?

Comment: If you don't think the designers were pro engineers, what is your motivation to ask questions about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q6 is an inverter and buffer in this circuit. It takes a low voltage control input, inverts it, and controls a 12V switch (Q3).

Q6's drain is pulled up to +12V which is needed to activate Q3. The buffer role of Q6 is to isolate the controlling device from the required +12V Q3 control voltage. Without it, the output of the controlling circuit would be pulled up to 12V.

Can this simple switch be implemented with only one FET? I can't see how. The crux is that it's the high side (BAT+) that is being switched on and off. If you were to switch GND instead, it could be done with a single FET and a resistor, but the switched ground circuit would not be interchangeable with the switched high side circuit.

Comment: thanks Jaredo makes sense.. but my only confusion still is when you say "Without it, the output of the controlling circuit would be pulled up to 12V." Why would this be the case? The logic level gate signal does not need to be at the same voltage going from source to drain ..

Comment: ah nevermind .. the pullup resistor .. missed it

Comment: The p FET needs a gate voltage (nearly) equal to its source voltage to start conducting (ie, 0V), and a gate voltage (nearly) equal to its drain voltage to stop conducting (ie, +12V). This range of 0-12V is what the controlling device would need to supply. A +5V voltage direct from the controlling input, at the drain of Q3, is not high enough to turn it off, which is why the open drain Q6 + pullup to +12V are needed.

Comment: this helps so much, thx dude, but isnt source voltage on the p fet 12V not 0?

Comment: you're right, I should have said "equal to drain to start conducting, and equal to source to stop conducting". I swapped the words source and drain in that sentence. In any case, when conducting, the drain is at +12V and gate at 0V. To turn it off, the gate voltage needs to be +12V (equal to source).